# CMake Error: variable set to NOTFOUND even after defining it manually

Tags: macos, cmake, glew

I am new to cmake and attempting to build an existing repository that relies on GLEW. I have installed GLEW using Homebrew and am now trying to run `cmake .` The configuration step completes, but the generation step raises the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLEW_LIBRARY
```

I have checked/tried the following:

- `CMakeLists.txt` contains a line `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` which does not fail. I even added the line `FIND_LIBRARY(GLEW_LIBRARY NAMES libGLEW.dylib PATHS /opt/local/lib /usr/local/lib /usr/lib REQUIRED)` to explicitly tell cmake where to look for the library and it finds the correct path.
- There is a file `FindGlew.cmake` that was placed in `/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.25.2/share/cmake/Modules` (I assume during the homebrew install of GLEW). It contains a line `unset(GLEW_LIBRARY)`. I'm a bit hesitant to mess with the file (it shouldn't be necessary, right?) but I tried commenting that line out and running `cmake` again, but it didn't have any effect.
- `CMakeCache.txt` contains the variables `GLEW_LIBRARY_DEBUG` and `GLEW_LIBRARY_RELEASE` which were set to `GLEW_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND` etc. I edited them manually to the path of the `libGLEW.dylib` file and added an additional path which I called `GLEW_LIBRARY`, but to no avail.
- `CMakeCache.txt` also contains a variable `GLEW_DIR` which is defined. There is a `GLEW_LIBRARY_DIR` which is also `NOTFOUND`.
- I passed the variable as an explicit command using `cmake . -DGLEW_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libGLEW.dylib`. I tried this both with and without first deleting the cache.
- Statically define the library using the approach in [this answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).
- `brew reinstall glew`.

I do have OpenGL installed as wel, but built from source (not via Homebrew). Could It have something to do with them not being linked correctly? OpenGL is found properly by `CMakeLists.txt`, so `cmake` must have access to its path somehow.

Edit: this is (a MWE of) the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)

project ("ProjectName" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
# set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE TRUE)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
# set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE FALSE)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*.cpp src/*.hpp *src/.h)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${sources})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

file(COPY ${RESOURCE_FILES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Resources)
```

Edit: for completeness, here is the full output / error message:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework   
-- Found GLEW: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glew/glew-config.cmake  
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLEW_LIBRARY
    linked by target "ProjectName" in directory /Users/user1/dev/project

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Comment: I've answered your question, however next time I would highly recommend copy-pasting the `CMakeLists.txt` file that you use in your project.

Comment: "I even added the line `FIND_LIBRARY(GLEW_LIBRARY NAMES libGLEW.dylib PATHS /opt/local/lib /usr/local/lib /usr/lib REQUIRED)` to explicitly tell cmake where to look for the library and it finds the correct path." - 1. **Where** exactly you have added that line, before `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` or after it? 2. **Why** do you think that CMake actually finds a correct path? (`find_library` supports `REQUIRED` only for project configured for CMake 3.18 or later). According to the error message, exactly `find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY)` call fails.

Comment: Milan: Thank you for the suggestion, I have now added (a shorter version of) the file that still produces the error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: 1. I have tried both, but neither option was successful. 2. I ran cmake using debug flags around the statement and it listed the path that it found. I did the same thing for the original `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` and it finds the `FindGLEW.cmake` and `GLEWConfig.cmake` at the locations where I'd expect (i.e., where they were installed by brew)

Comment: Post the entire error message. Also before you do that use the `GLEW::GLEW` imported target instead of `{GLEW_LIBRARIES}` this is most likely caused by something else that you are not posting here and overlooking. EDIT: Just so we understand each other I want the entire output of `cmake -S. -Bbuild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT2: According to [FindGLEW](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLEW.html) you should use one of the imported targets - `GLEW::GLEW` i.e.

```
target_link_libraries(your_target GLEW::GLEW ... )
```

I would also kindly ask you to post the new errors that you are getting related to the MRE you posted. I will update my answer accordingly.

---

EDIT: Because you mentioned that some people can compile it and some people can't. Look at this line right here:

```
find_package(GLEW CONFIG QUIET)

if(GLEW_FOUND)
#...
```

This line tries to find the actual `GLEWConfig.cmake` file to configure this. Meaning that if you've installed the package **OR** they have in a way that you **have** this `GLEWConfig.cmake` file then you will get different results.

My recommendation is: Figure out exactly how they installed their GLEW (or if they compiled it) and recreate the exact same environment.

---

Here is the link to [FindGLEW.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake). On [Lines 41-58](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake#L41-L58) you can see the variables that you can use in your project. There is **NO** `GLEW_LIBRARY`.

If you look down in the file you'll see why:

```
if(GLEW_FOUND)
  find_package_handle_standard_args(GLEW DEFAULT_MSG GLEW_CONFIG)
  get_target_property(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS GLEW::GLEW INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
  set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  get_target_property(_GLEW_DEFS GLEW::GLEW INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
  if("${_GLEW_DEFS}" MATCHES "GLEW_STATIC")
    get_target_property(GLEW_LIBRARY_DEBUG GLEW::GLEW IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG)
    get_target_property(GLEW_LIBRARY_RELEASE GLEW::GLEW IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
  else()
    get_target_property(GLEW_LIBRARY_DEBUG GLEW::GLEW IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG)
    get_target_property(GLEW_LIBRARY_RELEASE GLEW::GLEW IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE)
  endif()
  get_target_property(_GLEW_LINK_INTERFACE GLEW::GLEW IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES_RELEASE) # same for debug and release
  list(APPEND GLEW_LIBRARIES ${_GLEW_LINK_INTERFACE})
  list(APPEND GLEW_LIBRARY ${_GLEW_LINK_INTERFACE})
  select_library_configurations(GLEW)
  if("${_GLEW_DEFS}" MATCHES "GLEW_STATIC")
    set(GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARIES ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
  else()
    set(GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARIES ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}) 
  endif()
  unset(_GLEW_DEFS)
  unset(_GLEW_LINK_INTERFACE)
  unset(GLEW_LIBRARY) #<-- here the temporary variable is unset
  unset(GLEW_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
  unset(GLEW_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
  return()
endif()
```

`GLEW_LIBRARY` is a temporary variable used to set **other** variables.

What instead you want to use is: `GLEW_LIBRARIES`

Comment: `GLEW_LIBRARY` is used inside the existing project that I'm trying to compile (it is a research project I'm joining). I didn't make any changes to the code yet (except the above debug attempts to build the code). Is it safe to say that the developer of that project erroneously called the variable? They're able to build the code without any problems though.

Comment: @Borage They might be using an older `FindXYZ.cmake` file. Additional option is that because it is poorly written, you are instead picking up a `GLEWConfig.cmake` file etc... that might be setting different variables altogether. Change the `CMakeLists.txt` and see what happens - without providing us with the actual project there's not much else we can tell you about this. However considering you're getting the error you're getting - my answer is most likely a possible solution.

Comment: @Borage In general, let me reassure you that the majority of `CMakeLists.txt` files out there are so badly written that these problems are more than common. We could perhaps point out some issues with it if we had the actual file in front of us (pasted in the question).

Comment: @MilanŠ.: Note that error message is not necessary caused by a project accessing exactly `GLEW_LIBRARY` variable. It is very possible that the project accesses (correctly!) `GLEW_LIBRARIES` variable, but the latter is constructed using the value of `GLEW_LIBRARY` variable. Technically, the error message is caused by **value** `GLEW_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND` found in some target's property at the end of the configuration process. Normally such value is created only by `find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY)` call, this is why CMake tells about `GLEW_LIBRARY` **variable**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev As Borage mentioned they are actively using the variable and also they are getting a specific `CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, ...`  which indicates that they are indeed using `GLEW_LIBRARY` instead of the proper variables or aliases.

Comment: Changing `${GLEW_LIBRARIES}` into `GLEW::GLEW` did the trick, thank you! cmake now completes successfully. Could you explain why the `${GLEW_LIBRARIES}` did not work for GLEW, but `${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}` (which was linked in the same line in my code) does work? Or should I change that to one of the imported targets as well?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to. It's all dependent on the author of the library (or the precursor files to the `xyz-config.cmake` file). Some people tend to define special "aliases" that do everything for you. Some just use the old way of defining a set of variables. It really depends on the library. I wouldn't worry about it too much.